# Creating a Football Field in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a Football Field in HTML & CSS but i'm stuck. I tried debugging this for hours already but to no avail.

Here's my code:

```css
#EndZone {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
.TopHash div {
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
#MiddleTopHash div {
  margin-top: 170px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
}
.MiddleBottomHash div {
  margin-top: 270px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
}
.BottomHash div {
  margin-top: 470px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="FootballField">
  <div id="EndZone"></div>
  <div class="TopHash">
    <div id="OneYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwoYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="ThreeYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="FourYardLineTopHash"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="FiveYardLine"></div>
  <div class="TopHash">
    <div id="SixYardLine"></div>
    <div id="SevenYardLine"></div>
    <div id="EightYardLine"></div>
    <div id="NineYardLine"></div>
    <div id="TenYardLine"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="MiddleTopHash">
    <div id="OneYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwoYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="MiddleBottomHash">
    <div id="OneYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwoYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="BottomHash">
    <div id="OneYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwoYardLineBottomHash"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
How do I get this following CSS rule to get every hash 30px to the right of each other?

```
.TopHash div {
    left: 300px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

edit 2:
This is the result I want:
[image: Football Field]

The only difference is that I want the yard hashes to be 30px away from each other

Comment: "I tried debugging this for hours already but to no avail" - so, what you tried to change?

Comment: The float: , display: .

Comment: My code is still not doing what I want it to do

Comment: Why don't you simply add `position: relative;` to your `FootballField` class and then layout the `div`s inside it as `position: absolute;`? Would be simpler using `top: <XX>px;`, `left: <XX>px;`, `top: <XX>px;` and `bottom: <XX>px;`.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: A regular Football Field (hashes every yard)

Comment: I still can't get my code to show each hash 30px away from each other

Comment: An image of the desired result might be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't everbody know what a Football Field looks like. Search "Football Field" on Google or Bing images and you'll find what I want my expected result to be. The only difference is 30px in between the yard hashes.

Comment: Look in to CSS 2D Transforms and CSS 3D Transforms; they are exactly what you want.

Comment: What does that have to do with aligning yard hashes 30px to the right of each other?

Comment: I took a crack at a responsive (scalable) football field earlier, which I understand is not what you want, but your poor attitude leave me not wanting to help any further. Here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zqghnzgf/2/

Comment: The thing you're fighting is that HTML is for marking up documents and is not a language for creating graphics. CSS isn't designed for that either. It's for styling documents. When you try, as too many do, to treat either as graphics programs, you waste time and needless words and won't get much in the way of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i'm going to do this the hard way

HTML:

```
    <div class="FootballField">
    <div id="EndZone"></div>
    <div class="TopHash">
    <div id="OneYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwoYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="ThreeYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="FourYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="SixYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="SevenYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="EightYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="NineYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="ElevenYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwelveYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="ThirteenYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="FourteenYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="SixteenYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="SeventeenYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="EighteenYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="NineteenYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyOneYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyTwoYardLineTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyThreeYardLineTopHash"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="MiddleTopHash">
    <div id="OneYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwoYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="ThreeYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="FourYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="SixYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="SevenYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="EightYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="NineYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="ElevenYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwelveYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="ThirteenYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="FourteenYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="SixteenYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="SeventeenYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="EighteenYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="NineteenYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyOneYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyTwoYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyThreeYardLineMiddleTopHash"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="MiddleBottomHash">
    <div id="OneYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwoYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="ThreeYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="FourYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="SixYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="SevenYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="EightYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="NineYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="ElevenYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwelveYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="ThirteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="FourteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="SixteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="SeventeenYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="EighteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="NineteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyOneYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyTwoYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyThreeYardLineMiddleBottomHash"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="BottomHash">
    <div id="OneYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwoYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="ThreeYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="FourYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="SixYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="SevenYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="EightYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="NineYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="ElevenYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwelveYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="ThirteenYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="FourteenYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="SixteenYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="SeventeenYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="EighteenYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="NineteenYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyOneYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyTwoYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    <div id="TwentyThreeYardLineBottomHash"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="FiveYardLine"></div>
    <div id="TenYardLineTopMark">&lt10</div>
    <div id="TenYardLine"></div>
    <div id="TenYardLineBottomMark">&lt10</div>
    <div id="FifteenYardLine"></div>
    <div id="TwentyYardLineTopMark">&lt20</div>
    <div id="TwentyYardLine"></div>
    <div id="TwentyYardLineBottomMark">&lt20</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #EndZone{float: left; width: 300px; height: 500px; background-color: red;}
    .TopHash div{width: 30px; height: 30px; border-right: 1px solid white; position: absolute;}
    #OneYardLineTopHash{left: 300px;}
    #TwoYardLineTopHash{left: 330px;}
    #ThreeYardLineTopHash{left: 360px;}
    #FourYardLineTopHash{left: 390px;}
    #SixYardLineTopHash{left: 450px;}
    #SevenYardLineTopHash{left: 480px;}
    #EightYardLineTopHash{left: 510px;}
    #NineYardLineTopHash{left: 540px;}
    #ElevenYardLineTopHash{left: 600px;}
    #TwelveYardLineTopHash{left: 630px;}
    #ThirteenYardLineTopHash{left: 660px;}
    #FourteenYardLineTopHash{left: 690px;}
    #SixteenYardLineTopHash{left: 750px;}
    #SeventeenYardLineTopHash{left: 780px;}
    #EighteenYardLineTopHash{left: 810px;}
    #NineteenYardLineTopHash{left: 840px;}
    #TwentyOneYardLineTopHash{left: 900px;}
    #TwentyTwoYardLineTopHash{left: 930px;}
    #TwentyThreeYardLineTopHash{left: 960px;}

    .MiddleTopHash div{top: 170px; width: 30px; height: 30px; border-right: 1px solid white; position: absolute;}
    #OneYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 300px;}
    #TwoYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 330px;}
    #ThreeYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 360px;}
    #FourYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 390px;}
    #SixYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 450px;}
    #SevenYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 480px;}
    #EightYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 510px;}
    #NineYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 540px;}
    #ElevenYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 600px;}
    #TwelveYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 630px;}
    #ThirteenYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 660px;}
    #FourteenYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 690px;}
    #SixteenYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 750px;}
    #SeventeenYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 780px;}
    #EighteenYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 810px;}
    #NineteenYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 840px;}
    #TwentyOneYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 900px;}
    #TwentyTwoYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 930px;}
    #TwentyThreeYardLineMiddleTopHash{left: 960px;}

    .MiddleBottomHash div{top: 270px; width: 30px; height: 30px; border-right: 1px solid white; position: absolute;}
    #OneYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 300px;}
    #TwoYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 330px;}
    #ThreeYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 360px;}
    #FourYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 390px;}
    #SixYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 450px;}
    #SevenYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 480px;}
    #EightYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 510px;}
    #NineYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 540px;}
    #ElevenYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 600px;}
    #TwelveYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 630px;}
    #ThirteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 660px;}
    #FourteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 690px;}
    #SixteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 750px;}
    #SeventeenYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 780px;}
    #EighteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 810px;}
    #NineteenYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 840px;}
    #TwentyOneYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 900px;}
    #TwentyTwoYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 930px;}
    #TwentyThreeYardLineMiddleBottomHash{left: 960px;}

    .BottomHash div{top: 470px; width: 30px; height: 30px; border-right: 1px solid white; position: absolute;}
    #OneYardLineBottomHash{left: 300px;}
    #TwoYardLineBottomHash{left: 330px;}
    #ThreeYardLineBottomHash{left: 360px;}
    #FourYardLineBottomHash{left: 390px;}
    #SixYardLineBottomHash{left: 450px;}
    #SevenYardLineBottomHash{left: 480px;}
    #EightYardLineBottomHash{left: 510px;}
    #NineYardLineBottomHash{left: 540px;}
    #ElevenYardLineBottomHash{left: 600px;}
    #TwelveYardLineBottomHash{left: 630px;}
    #ThirteenYardLineBottomHash{left: 660px;}
    #FourteenYardLineBottomHash{left: 690px;}
    #SixteenYardLineBottomHash{left: 750px;}
    #SeventeenYardLineBottomHash{left: 780px;}
    #EighteenYardLineBottomHash{left: 810px;}
    #NineteenYardLineBottomHash{left: 840px;}
    #TwentyOneYardLineBottomHash{left: 900px;}
    #TwentyTwoYardLineBottomHash{left: 930px;}
    #TwentyThreeYardLineBottomHash{left: 960px;}

    #FiveYardLine{left: 420px; width: 30px; height: 500px; border-right: 1px solid white; position: absolute;}
    #TenYardLineTopMark{left: 575px; top: 100px; color: white; position: absolute; font-size: 24px;}
    #TenYardLine{left: 570px; width: 30px; height: 500px; border-right: 1px solid white; position: absolute;}
    #TenYardLineBottomMark{left: 575px; top: 400px; color: white; position: absolute; font-size: 24px;}
    #FifteenYardLine{left: 720px; width: 30px; height: 500px; border-right: 1px solid white; position: absolute;}
    #TwentyYardLineTopMark{left: 875px; top: 100px; color: white; position: absolute; font-size: 24px;}
    #TwentyYardLine{left: 870px; width: 30px; height: 500px; border-right: 1px solid white; position: absolute;}
    #TwentyYardLineBottomMark{left: 875px; top: 400px; color: white; position: absolute; font-size: 24px;}
```